# How to deal with Resource Dictionaries, so they don't create unnecessary objects

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I moved some of my resources which are commonly used to a ResourceDictionary, example

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsCancel" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Close and save any changes you have made." />
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource XSaveCloseButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsCancel" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Close window." />
  </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

The reason for this is simple, I need the same styles in multiple places. But there is a problem I found, if somewhere I need to use CloseButtonStyle only, and I reference this resource dictionary. I think it creates both styles, I did a little test and on the code behind I looked by method FindResource to see whether I’ll get an instance of each style and I did.
So my question is how do I deal with this? I don’t want to create 2 objects if I only need one, but I also don’t want to write this styles by copying and pasting it in many places.

Comment: Make 2 dictionaries?

Comment: @Kilazur I thought about it, this is ok for small projects, but if I have few hundred styles for different controls, storyboards, data templates etc. Surely I don't want to have this many resource dictionaries

Comment: Eh, I don't know about that. For example, MahApps uses one dictionary per re-styled control, one dictionary per theme color, and two more dictionaries for light or dark theme. Even in UI design, separation of concerns is a thing ;) Why do you need to separate them? If you were looking for extreme performance, surely you wouldn't have ended with WPF :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Store styles in files in your working directory or resources (one file for one style)
2. Create class (for example ResourcesHolder) that will provide you resources by its Key (like FindResource does)
3. ResourcesHolder has FindResource(string resourceName) method that:

   - searches file in resources with the same name as resourceName
   - parses it with XamlReader and returns
4. ResourcesHolder class contains Dictionary where parsed objects are stored. To, if any resource had already been parsed, you will return it from this dictionary:

   ```
   private Dictionary<string, object> storedObjects;

   public object FindResource(string resourceName)
   {
       if (storedObjects.ContainsKey(resourceName))
           return storedObjects[resourceName];

       else
           //search, parse and return new resource
   }
   ```

   So, you can load every resource individually without loading anything else

**EDIT:**

Before calling Initialize() method you could load all the resources that you will need to create your window/usercontrol. In this case, you could add method to ResourceHolder:

```
    public void Load(string resourceName)
    {
        if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains(resourceName))
            return;
        else
        {
            var obj = /*load your resource here*/;
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(resourceName, obj)
        }
    }
```

And in your control/window:

```
    public partial class TestWindow : Window
    {
        public TestWindow()
        {
            ResourceHolder.Load("SaveButtonStyle");
            ResourceHolder.Load("CloseButtonStyle");
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

In this case in your xaml you can use {StaticResource} extension

If you want do it automatically in xaml like {StaticResource} or {DynamicResource}, you will have to write your own markupextension that would call Load or FindResource method of ResourceHolder itself

Comment: Hi VMaleev, thank you for your answer, so if I understand correctly, this will do two things (even more than I thought of  :) ). First of all it won’t create styles which I don’t need, and secondly, if a style was already created and something else calls for it, it will just reuse it instead of recreating it. Did I get it right?

Comment: Sounds good :) I guess the ResourceHolder needs to be static if I want to access it from many different views. The thing I don't understand is how when view is created I can intercept it to see whether the resource was already created, and then if I find it was, how do I stop the view from recreating it and using what's already there. Thank you :)

Comment: Please check my edit and if I did not answer your questions, feel free to ask it again =)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm starting from breaking the resource dictionaries down to files with single styles. And then I try the rest which makes more sense now  :)